# Looking for data type for sub-sub-sub member of Response object in Conversation API

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

In the Conversation API specification for the Response object there's an [ExpectedIntent](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/conversation#ExpectedIntent). It has a "input_value_spec.permission_value_spec" property with a "permissions" member. Permissions looks like the enums listed elsewhere in the spec ( request.conversation.type and request.inputs.raw_inputs.input_type ) but doesn't have the same Enum decorator. Any clue?

[image: ExpectedIntent in Response]

Comment: Please give a bit more information. What do you mean 'it's not set here'? Where is here in your case? This intent should be passed to the user and explain why you asking for a specific permission(s).

Comment: "Here" being the ExpectedIntent section of the Conversation API spec. Is "permissions" an Enum like request.conversation.type and request.inputs.raw_inputs.input_type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between `input_value_spec.permission_value_spec.permissions` and the Enums specified by `request.conversation.type` and `request.inputs.raw_inputs.input_type` is that `permissions` is not a type. It is an array. You can specify 0 or more of the permissions that you're asking for (as strings).

Now, it is like an Enum in that only those strings listed are (currently) supported, but it is different in that the types require exactly one of those values.